# What is the most appropriate algorithm to detect road in outdoor terrain?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision

I would like to detect road in outdoor scenario as seen in the picture on the left side and produce a black/white map as seen on the right side.

[outdoor scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUOlC.jpg)

I've been experimenting with neural networks but the required transformation must have the same dimension of the input and output image. Also CNNs seem useless to me because i don't want to categorize what's in the picture. Should i rather try some approach without NN and use some simple filters to detect edges?

Comment: that's a very difficult problem, especially with leaves on the ground. you can implement something on that will work for this very scenario but most likely fail on others. finding the center road isn't difficult, finding the crossing path till its narrow end will be pretty impossible unless you apply some complex model

Comment: Unfortunately this questions is not appropriate for SO, but I will give you a tip: CNNs are what you want, look into Semantic Segmentation and Fully Convolutional Networks.